# Unable to configure database in joomla installation on wamp server

Tags: joomla, wampserver

I am using both an IIS and wamp server in parallel on my system. I changed the wampserver port to `localhost:8080` in the `httpd.conf`, but during the joomla installation,it is getting stuck on the database configuration using following information:

> hostname:localhost:8080,
>   username and password:root,
>   database name:mydatabase (i created with wamp's phpmyadmin).

I dont know why it is getting stuck. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port `8080` is the port to your website, not your database. Try omitting the `8080` port and use the default `3306` MySQL port.